# Explicitly defaults by __defaults__ to overcome mutable issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I looked at the famous "[gotcha](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)" of mutable default arguments. The issue is that mutable defaults is only set in function definition and not during function call. The recommended remedy there and other places is to do:

```
def append_to(element, to=None):
    if to is None:
        to = []
    to.append(element)
    return to
```

But I thought that instead I may do this:

```
def append_to(element, to=[]):
    append_to.__defaults__ = ([],)
    to.append(element)
    return to
```

Do you see any problem or pitfall with this approach? Coding practices wise?

Comment: This is purely opinion based but for starters it will trigger lint tools, and I find it less readable than the first form.

Comment: That creates a new list instance in *every* call, even when it was unnecessary to do so (i.e. when `to` was actually passed in). And it doesn't generalize well if there are some other default arguments in the function. Recommend to just use the usual "if arg is None" pattern, which is readable and immediately recognizable by any Python developer - it's the usual pattern because it's the best way.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think `__defaults__` is an implementation detail of CPython, not something defined as part of the language.

Answer (score 0):

This is thread-unsafe and non-reentrant. Call it from multiple threads, or from a `__del__` method or something else that interrupts another `append_to` call, and you end up reusing the mutable default. You're going to have a heck of a time tracking that bug down.